# $\sum^n_{j=0} (-1)^{j-1}j $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find a formula for the alternating series 
$S_n= \sum^n_{j=0} (-1)^{j-1}j $ in terms of n but I'm blocked. By trial and error I know that it's equal to $\frac{ (-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{4} + \frac{1}{4}$ but I can't find a way from there. Anyone have a hint what to do please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Way 1**: split into two cases, $n$ even and $n$ odd. In the first case,

$$(1-2)+\cdots((2m-1)-2m)=\underbrace{(-1)+\cdots+(-1)}_m=-m,$$

where $n=2m$. Otherwise if $n=2m+1$ is odd,

$$\sum=(-m)+(2m+1)=m+1.$$

Glue these two together however one desires.

**Way 2**: an approach through "generating functions" would be to take the geometric sum formula,

$$1+x+\cdots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1},$$

take the derivative of both sides, then plug in $x=-1$.

Comment: Thanks just edited the question... Didn't realize it was so easy !!!

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solutions of the problem have been given by anon. We start instead at the stage at which by trial and error you reached the conjecture that $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{j-1}j=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$. The point we want to make is that *after the conjecture is made*, it can be proved *mechanically* by induction.  We provide two versions of the induction argument, one that has the traditional shape, and a second which is less traditional.

**Traditional induction:** Suppose that the conjecture is correct for $n=k$. We show that it is correct for $n=k+1$. So we are supposing that
$$\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j-1}j=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k+1)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}.\tag{$1$}$$
We have 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} (-1)^{j-1}j=\left(\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j-1}j\right) + (-1)^k(k+1).\tag{$2$}$$
By the induction hypothesis $(1)$, the right-hand side of $(2)$ is equal to 
$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k+1)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+ (-1)^k(k+1).\tag{$3$}$$
Note that $(-1)^k=(-1)^{k+2}$ and $(-1)^{k+1}=-(-1)^{k+2}$. It follows that expression $(3)$ is equal to 
$$(-1)^{k+2}\left(k+1 -\frac{2k+1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}.$$
This simplifies to $(-1)^{k+2}\frac{2(k+1)+1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$, which is *exactly* the assertion that the conjecture is correct for $n=k+1$.

**Another way:** The following is a better, but still mechanical, way to verify your conjecture. Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence whose $n$-th term is $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{j-1}j$. Let $(b_n)$ be the sequence whose $n$-th term is $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$. We want to show that the two sequences are the same. It is easy to verify that $a_1=b_1$. Note that the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies the recurrence
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+ (-1)^n(n+1).$$
If we can show that the sequence $(b_n)$ satisfies the *same recurrence*, we will be finished. So we want to show that $b_{n+1}-b_n=(-1)^n(n+1)$. Calculate.
$$b_{n+1}-b_n=\left( \frac{(-1)^{n+2}(2n+3)}{4}+\frac{1}{4} \right) -\left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}  \right).$$
The rest is routine algebra, using the fact that $(-1)^{n+2}=(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n+1}=-(-1)^n$.